# Android: Camera orientation when started by Intent

Tags: android, camera

I'm starting Camera application to take a picture via Intent:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), 0);
```

But camera is always in landscape mode, even when you rotate your handset to portrait mode. Is there any way to make camera detect current orientation?

Thanks

Comment: Just being curious, which device are you using to test this?

Comment: Droid X. But this behavior is also seen on other devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source for the camera app answers this question.  See below an excerpt from the camera app manifest file.  The screenOrientation tag is set to landscape.  This app will not display in portrait.  If you need portrait mode from a camera app then you may have to build your own.

```
<activity android:name="com.android.camera.Camera"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              **android:screenOrientation="landscape"**
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
              android:taskAffinity="android.task.camera">
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Although I cannot say I happy to know that :)